# Arduino Control Panel for windows

Tags: arduino

Does anybody here know a good windows program to control the Arduino Uno Board?

Simple things like graph view to test values of sensors... you know... something simple like this program for another board:

[image]

http://www.gogoboard.org/cocoon/gogosite/software/monitor/images/screenshot.jpg <sup>(dead link - [archive.org](http://web.archive.org/web/20071008144836if_/http://www.gogoboard.org/cocoon/gogosite/software/monitor/images/screenshot.jpg))</sup>

Answer (score 4):

You may want to take a look at Firmata.

There is a Firmata example that can be loaded into the Arduino from File > Examples > Firmata > StandardFirmata menu in the Arduino development environment.

You can download a PC host program from http://firmata.org/wiki/Main_Page for Linux, Windows, or Mac OS-X.

From Firmata main page,
"If you need to quickly test your hardware, this stand-alone program can access all pins. It runs from a single file (no installation needed), for quick and easy testing!"

Answer (score 3):

I'm judging from the tone of the question that you think the Uno is a general purpose I/O board for which it is simple to interface sensors or relays or other analog/digital devices and read/control them using software already on the board.  This is not the case.  The Uno is a general purpose microcontroller board that has no specific function unless you program it yourself.  It is certainly possible to use it in the manner you describe but you'll have to do all the work - analog/digital interface and software for both the Uno and PC.

A good path to creating the PC-side software would by Python I'd think.  You can create GUIs fairly easily and it's pleasant to work with.  Otherwise I don't know of any projects for the Arduino that mimic the functionality of the gogoboard.  Anyone know of any?

Comment: It is also easy to talk to serial devices using processing.

Comment: +1 for Python, I use it on the Mac to receive data from my Arduino app and display it in various graphs using TKinter for the user interface.

Comment: I'll give a second vote to processing, www.processing.org, it's arduino's companion on the computer.  There are lots of examples on the processing website about connecting with an arduino.  you should go check it out.
Jim